# Ganache with Metamask is filling command window with "eth_getBlockByNumber" string

Tags: testrpc

When connecting Metamask with Ganache-Cli, as soon it generates the accounts and keys, the command window is getting filled with "eth_getBlockByNumber" continuously[image], has anyone else faced the issue?

Thanks.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. What is happening???

Answer (score 1):

It's because Metamask is pooling for the latest block number.

See here : https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli-archive/issues/379

Answer (score 0):

you are running test RPC that is how it looks like. If you stop test RPC then your blocks would not be fixed in the chain, which is created internally in the system.

Answer (score 0):

What you see is ganache-cli logging.

You can turn it off using the `-q` option like so:

```
$ ganache-cli -q
```